# I am looking for sed command equivalent in python code

Tags: python

I have sed command to remove colour code characters and I am able to remove them with `sed -r 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g'` command. Please help me on making this command in python

I am trying this in python `line = line.replace('\x1b[31m', '')`. can we have entair command at a short

Answer (score 0):

You could use re (module for regular expressions in python):

```
import re
line = "uidhiohriopjh"
re_pattern = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]')
print(re.sub(re_pattern, '', line))
```

Answer (score 0):

str.replace(old, new[, count])
Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced. For more details pls refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

In your case
line = line.replace('\x1b[31m', '')
the above will replace the first occurance of '\x1b[31m' in the string with ''.